# What is the correct model/type SSD for an old MacBook Pro 13.3?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hdd, sata

I have an old MacBook Pro - it is:

- MBP 13.3/2.9/2X4GB/750/SD
- Model No: A1278

So far, it works in peace, it has a HDD of 750GB - in this point is not possible do an upgrade of the macOS itself. An option is use MacPorts.

Anyway - I want install Linux. Now, I want buy a new HD of 1TB but being SSD.

What is the correct model for this Mac? I want buy one based of WD (Western Digital) - I want from that company because for other laptop I bought:

- WD Blue SA510 SATA SSD
- 1TB of capacity
- WDS100T3B0A-00AXR0 (shown in back of the box package)

So far it is fast as expected. Theoretically it is:

- [Western Digital 1TB WD Blue SA510 SATA Internal Solid State Drive SSD - SATA III 6 Gb/s, 2.5"/7mm, Up to 560 MB/s - WDS100T3B0A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZYQ84CM)

But because this laptop is old, I am sure not sure about what is the correct model for this Mac.

Please confirm if this model is valid, if not, please share an URL of the recommended product.
My uncle should buy this HD in USA and I live in other country - so is not possible make a mistake.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: What year MacBook Pro is it?

Comment: @Allan: If "MBP 13.3/2.9" means "MBP 13.3"/2.9 GHz", then the year is [Mid-2012](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html). This is the only [A1278](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=a1278) with 2.9 GHz.

Comment: Any 2.5” (laptop) SSD will fit.  See the linked dupe.

Comment: Therefore: Does the WD SSD mentioned in the link can fit and work in peace?